# Xamarin Visual Studio not working Ajax on Local Files - IOS / IPHONE?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying create an app with Xamarin and HTML+Javascript.
But doesn't running ajax. Also I can't get queryString when I try in host domain too. And my domain have SSL (HTTPS).

Who can send-me a example that running? I'm build for IOS / IPHONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than Xamarins as IOS don't have full support on app. Only run in WebApp on Safari.